# jquerymobile - selectable list item

Tags: jquery-mobile

I want to be able to select a listview item. On select/click I can use onclick event and add class to that li. But, is there any default way in which I can select an item in the listview. I mean, when I select, it should be highlighted and I should be able to get the selected value.

Comment: add relevant details to your questions, what you've done so far and where are you stuck.

Comment: The jQM listview widget does not include any default functionality for a highlighted/selected item. Your approach of handling the click, adding a class and storing the currently selected item in a global or data-attribute is a good way to go.

Comment: Thanks @ezanker Please write answer so I can mark it as answer.

Comment: Thanks, i posted my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jQM listview widget does not include any default functionality for a highlighted/selected item. Your approach of

- handling the click,
- adding a class, and
- storing the currently
  selected item in a global or data-attribute

is a good way to go.